# Using Two Fonts (Fira) In A Article

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I have installed the Fira Sans Package, I use it with this code:

```
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

But this sets the whole article to Fira Fonts, is there anyway to use FiraSans font only in one part of the document, and the other part some other font, for example, some font from the Helvet package?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load `\usepackage{FiraSans}` with appropriate scaling, followed by the font you want as your main font, such as `lmodern` in PDFLaTeX or `newcomputermodern` in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

You will then be able to use the command `\firaproportional` to switch to Fira Sans within a group.  You could also define the helper commands

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textfira{\firaproportional}
```

to be able to write `\textfira{This is Fira Sans}`, or

```
\newenvironment{firasans}%
               {\begingroup\firaproportional}%
               {\endgroup}
```

to be able to use `\begin{firasans}`.

Comment: A lot of thanks